# What items should I buy from the shop before stealing the bow?

Tags: zelda-links-awakening-2019

I'm attempting a no death run to unlock that sweet seagull ending, and so after I steal the bow from the shop I never plan to return to it. I could just save up my rupees of course but, well, I'd rather just steal it. In order to get away from my thievery (mostly) consequence free,  I want to hold off on stealing the bow until there's nothing left at the shop but consumable items (i.e. arrows).

I know the shop contains the shovel and at least one heart container. I'm also under the impression that you need to buy the bombs from the shop before they'll start appearing as item drops (but I could be wrong on that). Is there anything else?

What items should I purchase from the shop before stealing the bow?

Comment: FWIW, you can accumulate rupees _very_ quickly in the Rapids Raid (+300 per run no problem), so maybe it's not worth stealing anything at all?

Comment: @BenP. Yeah but I'm a filthy thief.

Answer (score 2):

From what I saw while playing, theres at least :

- a heart piece
- a Dampe dungeon block

You might not want to steal the Bow as it's not the most expensive item anymore (the block being 1000ish).

Comment: I forgot about the chamber blocks, but I'm not going for 100% anyways, so I'm not worried about them. More importantly though, is that I'm playing on Hero Mode, during which the shopkeeper is way harder to steal from. The end result is that I just ended up stealing the bow anyways. Once I've finished this current playthrough I should be able to confirm if there's anything aside from what we've already listed.

Comment: The shop now sells several chamber stones, each for 1280 rupees, so you won't be able to 100% the game any more (without dying). I didn't pay massive attention to which chamber stones they were, but I think they tended to be unique ones - fairy fountains, extra boss fights and the like.